# How to init a git repo via FTP?

Tags: git, netbeans, ftp

I would like to create a git repo of my existing website, currently accessed only via ftp from Komodo Edit, and clone it into NetBeans 8.0 on Mac OS X.9 to deploy from there in the future.

I found [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp), installed it, and tried `$ git ftp init -u USERNAME -p - ftp://SERVER` as told in the readme.

Terminal tells me `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)`.

I only need the git-ftp tool to init a repo on the server (I guess I'll deploy via the NetBeans GUI) How do you properly do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the website via FTP to a local directory and then initialize the Git repo there.

Comment: Cheers! And then, how to tell git and NetBeans that [my server address] is the adresse where to deploy? Sorry I'm new to git. Edit: Can't vote you up, too new.